# JQPL select inside select

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpql

just switched to spring boot from .NET Core, in .NET core we can easily nest a select inside a select like this:

```
 var result = from c in context.Cars
                         join br in context.Brands
                         on c.BrandId equals br.Id
                         join col in context.Colors
                         on c.ColorId equals col.Id
                         select new CarDetailDto
                         {
                             Id = c.Id,
                             BrandName = br.Name,
                             CarName = c.Name,
                             ColorName = col.Name,
                             DailyPrice = c.DailyPrice,
                             ModelYear = c.ModelYear,
                             CarImages = (from cimg in context.CarImages
                                          where cimg.CarId == c.Id
                                          select new CarImage
                                          {
                                              Id = cimg.Id,
                                              ImagePath = cimg.ImagePath,
                                              CarId = c.Id,
                                              Date = cimg.Date
                                          }).ToList()
                         };
```

I want to do that in JPQL as well but didnt manage to solve

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: I have an entity that has one to many inside. Like a resume with job experiences , I have to JsonIgnore it due to infinite recursion, I want to get job experience list inside resume information to a DTO with @Query annotation But i couldnt write that JPQL

Basically i want to translate that .NET query on top to JPQL Query

Answer (score 1):

```
@Query( select column1, column2, column3 from tablename1 where coluname=(select columname from tablename2 where columnname=abcd) )
```

Your JPQL query should look like above.
Whatever subquery you write with condition.

If your query is fetching 3 column you need to create a DTO with same column name.

If your query is fetching list of rows then your actual jpql will look like this.

```
@Query( select column1, column2, column3 from tablename1 where coluname= 
(select columname from tablename2 where columnname=abcd) )
List<ResultDTO> findAllResultList(Parameter value);
```

Above it is mapping the result to list of DTO objects to result rows.

If your query is fetching single  row then your actual jpql will look like this.

```
@Query( select column1, column2, column3 from tablename1 where coluname= 
(select columname from tablename2 where columnname=abcd) )
ResultDTO findResult(Parameter value);
```

The single result is mapped to one DTO object.

Make sure your result column name and DTO column name matches
Using the JPA repository call the names of the method which you used for the particular query.